# Toggle button checked status on activity startup

Tags: android

Here's my code

```
public class Abc(){
Public void onCreate(){
Textview ustatus;
ustatus=(Textview)findviewbyid(R.id.status);
    statusButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        statusOnline();
                        // The toggle is enabled
                    } else {
                        statusOffline();
                        // The toggle is disabled
                    }
                }
            });
}

      public void statusOnline(){
               ustatus.setText("Online");
}
public void statusOffline(){
               ustatus.setText("Offline");
}
}
```

I want to know what toggle state would be at the initial on startup suppose in statusOnline and statusOffline method i am doing alot more so i just want that at initial this toggle is intialized with "ON" state.
I don't how to achieve it please bring some light into my code.

Comment: just don't add a OnCheckedChangeListener. Use an if statement: `if(checked){ setNotChecked(); } else{ setChecked(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"/>
```

This will create a checkbox that is already ticked. U can change the checked to false if u want an unchecked box. The listner will only call when u interact with the checkbox.

For listener outside onCreate u can do as follows

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //other statements here
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
         //process logic here

        }
    };

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.clear(); 
editor.commit();
```

Comment: can you tell me how to implement methods of onCheckchanged listenner outside of onCreate method this status works only when the activity is created then it doesn't so i want to implement OnCheckchanged listenner like some button listenner

Comment: please see my updated answer and if u have more doubt don't hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: I have used toggle button though

Comment: same logic .u can use toggle btn instead of checkbox like this also

Comment: I know i was just telling can you tell me one thing more suppose i want to clear preferences which is saved in my project using preference manager how to delete it manually please one last query then i am done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128324/discussion-between-sameerkhan1406-and-vicky).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`boolean mBool = true;
mToggle.setChecked(mBool);`

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your `onCreate` method just after initializing the statusButton

```
 statusButton.setchecked(true);
```